# defined function call returns name not defined error

Tags: python-3.x, function, nameerror

I have defined a following function:

```
def create_table(table,L):
    table={'BBGTicker':L}
    table=pd.DataFrame(table)
    return table
```

trying to execute for example:

```
c=create_table(c,put_options_create)
```

where put_options_create is a list returns following error:

name 'c' is not defined.

If I was to write:

```
c={'BBGTicker':put_options_create}
c=pd.DataFrame(c)
```

this would work and give me a table.

What is wrong with the above function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first parameter of `create_table` is useless. `table`, the parameter, is immediately overwritten by `table={'BBGTicker':L}`, so there's no point in having that parameter.

Just change the function to:

```
def create_table(L):
    table={'BBGTicker':L}
    table=pd.DataFrame(table)
    return table
```

and then call it as

```
c=create_table(put_options_create)
```

To answer why this is the case though: the variables between the `()` during a function call must already exist. If you haven't already assigned `c` a value, `create_table(c,put_options_create)` doesn't make sense. You only supply data there that you're **giving** a function. You don't specify in the parameter list data that you expect to get back`*`.

---

`*` It is possible to "return" data via parameters via mutation of objects, but that isn't what you're attempting to do here.